# Task.Factory.StartNew not executing method

Tags: entity-framework, async-await

I have an Entity Framework method which simply adds a `Product` to the database. When I run my test method this all works as expected.

I then have an `AddProductAsync` method:

```
Task<Product> AddProductAsync(Product pToAdd)
{
    return Task<Product>.Factory.StartNew(() => AddProduct(pToAdd));
}
```

When I run the test using this method the test runs but nothing actually happens. The break point in my `AddProduct` method is never hit and nothing is added to the database. There is no error, no warning.

What am I doing wrong? Or shall I just wait for EF6?

Thanks in advance

Original Method:

```
public static Product AddProduct(Product pToAdd)
    {
        using (var viralDatabase = new ViralWearContext())
        {
            if (viralDatabase.Products.Any(p => p.Name == pToAdd.Name || p.Description == pToAdd.Description))
            {
                var result = viralDatabase.Products.First(p => p.Name == pToAdd.Name || p.Description == pToAdd.Description);
                //set 0 so client knows it already exists
                result.ProductID = 0;
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = viralDatabase.Products.Add(pToAdd);
                viralDatabase.SaveChanges();
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Method called by Unit Test:

```
public async void AddProductsAsyncTest()
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

        Product testProduct = GenerateTestProduct();
        Product testProductTwo = GenerateTestProduct();
        Product testProductThree = GenerateTestProduct();
        timer.Start();

        Product_Datalayer.AddProduct(testProduct);
        Product_Datalayer.AddProduct(testProductTwo);
        Product_Datalayer.AddProduct(testProductThree);
        var time1 = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

        timer.Reset();

        Product testProductAsync = GenerateTestProduct();
        Product testProductTwoAsync = GenerateTestProduct();
        Product testProductThreeAsync = GenerateTestProduct();
        timer.Start();

        var result1 = Product_Datalayer.AddProductAsync(testProductAsync);
        var result2 = Product_Datalayer.AddProductAsync(testProductTwoAsync);
        var result3 = Product_Datalayer.AddProductAsync(testProductThreeAsync);

        await Task.WhenAll(result1, result2, result3);
        var time2 = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the whole code, with AddProduct method and calling context?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test (I do not have .net 4.5), but it could be related to a problem with await/Tasks. Does the WhenAll return immediately? Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950329/how-to-use-task-whenall-correctly

Comment: It doesn't return immediately. It will hang on that point for a few seconds then end the debug as if completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [make your unit tests `async Task`, not `async void`](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html). Note that `async` unit tests are only supported by VS2012.

If you're on VS2010, you can use the [Async Unit Tests project described here](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-2-right-way.html). I still recommend you use `async Task`, so they will translate easily to VS2012 (which is *not* supported by the Async Unit Tests project).